# PHP: PDFlib, OOP & Comments

Tags: php, class, pdf, pdflib

Since PHP 4.0.5 there are functions to dynamically generate PDFs (PDFlib).
I have 3 questions to the PDFlib:

1. Is there an OOP class? If not, is it planned in a future version of PHP?
2. Is there a function to add comments to a pdf AND override the old one?
3. Is there an alternative, which is able to do the things above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PHP5 there is OOP version on PDFlib. Check it here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.pdf.php
As i know, you can't use it full version for commercial purpose. You can try to use FPDF instead: http://www.fpdf.org/

Answer (score 1):

I use this library to create PDF on the fly ezPDF http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdf-php/, could make a very complex PDF's in a relative easy way. His Manual is created using the library. http://pdf-php.sf.net/pdf-php-code/readme.pdf